# Why I can not use the received data in a URLConnection for later use?

Tags: android

Please see the following code.In the following code when I use the `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`, I can see the 
contents of the `text` string in a `Toast` widget, But when I want to use the 
contents of the `text` string for later use such as the going to the other activity, I am mot successful to do this. Note that my `php` code sends only the `yes` stream to the android and my condition in the following code is true.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   try{
        GetText();
    }
catch(Exception e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
void GetText(){
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String text = null;
    try{
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/request.php");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line);
        }


        text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    // Show response on activity
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(text.equals("yes")){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Test.class);//I can not go to the Test.class
startActivity(intent);
}}
    }
```

**PHP.CODE**

```
<?php

echo "yes";
?>
```

Comment: is your application crashing or you are remaining on the same activity?

Comment: if you move the toast are you still seeing it? Are you sure there's no whitespaces or similar stuff in the output of your PHP script (**watch out** for trailing newline after `?>`)

Comment: I updated my post. Please see the my `php` code. Also when I launch my code I see only the `Toast`widget and I am in the `MainActivity` class still and not in `Test` class. This problem is very strange.

Comment: Why are you calling URLConnection from UI-thread? It must be in a background thread, usually AsyncTask. Also, after receving data you should start intent from UI-thread (as in your code is now). Are you sure `text.equals("yes")` is true?